# HTML Table Row nth-child Dynamic Content Issue

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a table whose `<tr>`s I populate on the fly by manually changing the table's `innerHTML`. When I do, the CSS I have in place (which implements `nth-child(odd/even)`) fails.

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #000000;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

The resulting table has all `<tr>`s with the color scheme of an `nth-child(odd)` selector.

When the table is populated dynamically with `tableVar.innerHTML += "<tr>...</tr>"` the issue arises, however, it turns out if you change the way the `innerHTML` is modified by first assembling a string with `stringVar += "<tr>...</tr>"` and then assigning the innerHTML to the string with `tableVar.innerHTML = stringVar` the problem goes away and the expected behavior returns.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser wraps your new rows in `<tbody>` elements when you concatenate a new row directly to the table element, so each subsequent row is a single row per new `<tbody>`, making it apply to the `nth-child(odd)` selector. This explains why constructing new HTML from scratch and assigning it to the table doesn't show that problem. You can see this by inspecting the HTML generated in your browser's developer console when you run this example:

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table");
setInterval(function() {
  table.innerHTML += "<tr><td>Test1</td><td>Test 2</td></tr>";
}, 1000)
```

```css
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you append directly to the table's `<tbody>` element instead, you'll see the CSS apply to your new rows as expected:

```js
var tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
setInterval(function() {
  tbody.innerHTML += "<tr><td>Test1</td><td>Test 2</td></tr>";
}, 1000)
```

```css
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```